# How to set dynamic image path

Tags: javascript, html

I want to use dynamic variable for my image.

I have something like

```
var img = 'test'

var path = "<img src="'../images/' + img + '_default_path.png'"></img>";
```

but it gave me errors. I know it might be just the quote issue but I am not sure where went wrong. Can someone please help me on this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: why the </img> the img tag is a stand alone tag

Comment: have you tried debugging and see what path ends up being? I don't think you need the 'double quotes' around '../images/' + img + '_default_path.png'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
var path = '<img src="../images/' + img + '_default_path.png" />';
```